# SwiftUI problem (With list and simulator)

Tags: list, swiftui, ios-simulator

I'm starting to learn swiftUI and I have a strange problem,
I have created a simple list that displays perfectly in the preview... But not in the simulator.
Does anyone have an idea?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/eo1ldvdbgntzr8v/Enregistrement%20de%20l%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202021-06-04%20%C3%A0%2018.42.03.mov?dl=0

Project : https://github.com/maxupcreation/Dfi/tree/main/Dfi

Comment: Share minimum reproducible code with us, so someone can debug and let you know the issue.

Answer (score 1):

to answer more correctly, you'd better show us yout whole source code.

it seems second view(maybe AddChallengeView.swift file)'s input cannot reflect to original view(=ContentView.swift)'s List. so there might be two problems

1. because you refer your "items" property from another view, you'd better check if you use `ObservableObject` protocol and `@ObservedObject` property wrapper properly.
2. at `ForEach` statement, you use nil coalescing, so check whether item value is `nil`

Comment: Thanks ! I add project ( https://github.com/maxupcreation/Dfi/tree/main/Dfi )